# Continuous CSS rotation animation on hover, animated back to 0deg on hover out

Tags: css, css-animations

I have an element that spins when you hover over it indefinitely. When you hover out, the animation stops. Simple:

```
@-webkit-keyframes rotate {
    from {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    to { 
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}

.elem:hover {
    -webkit-animation-name: rotate; 
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s; 
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
}
```

When you hover out, though, the animation abruptly ceases, reverting to 0 degrees. I'd like to animate back to that position, but I'm having some trouble working out the syntax.

Any input would be awesome!

Comment: To be honnest, I don't think you can. I created a jsFiddle anyway, so if anyone have an idea... http://jsfiddle.net/4Vz63/1/

Comment: Thanks for the jsfiddle - stumped myself, it seems like it should be possible with keyframes, but I'm not all that familiar with CSS# animation syntaxes yet.

Comment: I think you can get the reverse effect of an animation only by using the -webkit-transition property and not with the -webkit-animation

Comment: Of course you can do that in JS but not in pure CSS. Also please check this solution which is kind of close to what you want - http://jsfiddle.net/SebastianPataneMasuelli/nkEwQ/7/

Answer (score 88, accepted):

The solution is to set the default value in your .elem.
But this annimation work fine with -moz but not yet implement in -webkit

Look at the fiddle I updated from yours :
http://jsfiddle.net/DoubleYo/4Vz63/1648/

It works fine with Firefox but not with Chrome

```css
.elem{
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
    left: 40px;
    width: 0; 
    height: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 75px;
    border-color: red blue green orange;
    transition-property: transform;
    transition-duration: 1s;
}
.elem:hover {
    animation-name: rotate; 
    animation-duration: 2s; 
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
}

@keyframes rotate {
    from {transform: rotate(0deg);}
    to {transform: rotate(360deg);}
}
```

```html
<div class="elem"></div>
```

Comment: Great fiddle mate ( or fiffle ;) )

Comment: I'm a complete arse for somehow not noticing this answer. A fix in FF is better than nothing, could be patched with JS to work in Chrome.

Comment: Tried jFiddle it Worked nicely in chrome and I abrupt animation in FF. Looks like if increase the animation duration then rotation works nicely. Something like `-moz-animation-duration: 6s` (nothing magical about 6s) 1.5s is too fast for FF

Comment: One of my fav fiddle of all time, i love changing `border-style`

Comment: This is not working for me in Chrome 35. It works (kind of) in FF 30. If I mouse over, leave, then mouse over before it resets to 0, it finishes the animation then jumps to start the infinite rotation animation.

Comment: updated fiddle, removing -moz- prefix => http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-animation | http://jsfiddle.net/scheinercc/30sxLud3/2/

Comment: what does transition-property: transform;    transition-duration: 10s; do?  seems to work if these lines are deleted??

Answer (score 16):

Here's a simple working solution:

```
@-moz-keyframes spin { 100% { -moz-transform: rotate(360deg); } }
@-webkit-keyframes spin { 100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); } }
@keyframes spin { 100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); transform:rotate(360deg); } }

.elem:hover {
    -webkit-animation:spin 1.5s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation:spin 1.5s linear infinite;
    animation:spin 1.5s linear infinite;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Cross browser compatible JS solution:

```js
var e = document.getElementById('elem');
var spin = false;

var spinner = function(){
e.classList.toggle('running', spin);
if (spin) setTimeout(spinner, 2000);
}

e.onmouseover = function(){
spin = true;
spinner();
};

e.onmouseout = function(){
spin = false;
};
```

```css
body { 
height:300px; 
}
#elem {
position:absolute;
top:20%;
left:20%;
width:0; 
height:0;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 75px;
border-color: red blue green orange;
border-radius: 75px;
}

#elem.running {
animation: spin 2s linear 0s infinite;
}

@keyframes spin { 
100% { transform: rotate(360deg); } 
}
```

```html
<div id="elem"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It took a few tries, but I was able to get your jsFiddle to work (for Webkit only).

There's still an issue with the animation speed when the user re-enters the div.

Basically, just set the current rotation value to a variable, then do some calculations on that value (to convert to degrees), then set that value back to the element on mouse move and mouse enter.

Check out the jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4Vz63/46/

Check out this article for more information, including how to add cross-browser compatibility:
http://css-tricks.com/get-value-of-css-rotation-through-javascript/

Answer (score 0):

Here's a javascript implementation that works with web-kit:

```
var isHovering = false;

var el = $(".elem").mouseover(function(){
    isHovering = true;
    spin();
}).mouseout(function(){
    isHovering = false;
});

var spin = function(){
    if(isHovering){
        el.removeClass("spin");

        setTimeout(function(){
            el.addClass("spin");

            setTimeout(spin, 1500);
        }, 0);
    }
};
spin();
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4Vz63/161/

Barf.

Answer (score -1):

```
<script>
var deg = 0

function rotate(id)
{
    deg = deg+45;
    var txt = 'rotate('+deg+'deg)';
    $('#'+id).css('-webkit-transform',txt);
}
</script>
```

What I do is something very easy... declare a global variable at the start... and then increment the variable however much I like, and use .css of jquery to increment.

Comment: Thanks, but the question was on CSS.

Answer (score -2):

You should trigger the animation to revert once it's completed w/ javascript.

```
  $(".item").live("animationend webkitAnimationEnd", function(){
    $(this).removeClass('animate');
  });
```

Comment: This is incorrect. The question was based on `CSS` and it is, and was, already possible with `CSS`. Hence the downvote