# How to Make a Picture rotate Continuously?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

) I have a star image in top-left of my screen want to rotate continuously. so can anyone tell me How can we make a Picture rotate Continuously for browsers Mozilla Firefox, Google chrome!?
[Css Position type is 'Absolutely' and image resolution:25*25 ]

Comment: As it is small why not make an animated gif?

Comment: this is obviously a preloader. no need for extra javascript and code and loading times for something that would be 1kb more as a GIF, especially jQuery

Comment: CarrieKendall : jquerycss and it doesn't work on Google Chrome Browser!:O  
cosmorogers : you're right;) i'm going to try it for this one and there's some another images so also i needed a code for them!:O tnx 4 great idea;;)  
rickyduck : good idea!:-!:-/;)

Comment: If you just want a preloader image, maybe this could be of any use: http://ajaxload.info/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7988962/continuous-css-rotation-animation-on-hover-animated-back-to-0deg-on-hover-out

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
@-webkit-keyframes rotate {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to { 
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

img.star {
    -webkit-animation-name:            rotate; 
    -webkit-animation-duration:        0.5s; 
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
}
```

Add `-moz-transform/animation`, `-ms-transform/animation`, etc rules to support other browsers.

You could also make an animated GIF :).

### Update

Animation support is available is most current browsers which means that the prefixes can be removed:

*(For reverse rotation flip the 'from' and 'to')*

```
@keyframes rotate {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to { 
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

img.star {
    animation-name:            rotate; 
    animation-duration:        0.5s; 
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
}
```

Shorthand:

```
img.star {
    animation: rotate 0.5s infinite linear;
}
```

Comment: GIF is heavier. Your solution looks like the best pratice.

Comment: Animations are well supported nowadays: https://caniuse.com/#search=animation
So I updated the answer

Answer (score 8):

## You can do that with CSS: (utilizing your GPU core):

```css
img{ 
    animation:2s rotate infinite linear; 
}

@keyframes rotate{
    100%{ transform:rotate(1turn) } // or 360deg
}
```

```html
<img src="https://ih0.redbubble.net/image.364229144.1663/flat,200x200,075,t.jpg">
```

Comment: except for older browsers which I assume they're targeting

Comment: he explicitly said he DOES NOT target them.

Comment: No, he said for "Mozilla Firefox, Google chrome", FF especially with versions 3.1 and below css transition support was minimal and non-existant (bear in mind ff 3.1 did not have an automatic updater and many people still use it)

Comment: are u enjoying harassing me? this is the answer and that is it.

Comment: I'm merely stating the point as this is a community site and other people may view this answer, whats wrong with me adding to your answer?

Comment: Fair point, but knowledge is wealth :)

Comment: + this answer is definitely the best for the title of the question, as it could apply to a full size image as opposed to a 25x25 preloader for which a GIF would not be applicable and jQuery might not be available, and javascript too complex

Comment: ok I agree, but seriously, FF usage below version 5 (for CSS3 animation) are quite low and falling. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firefox#Market_adoption

Answer (score 3):

You could use RaphaelJS, since it's cross-browser compatible.  For example, this code should work:

`<div id="paper" style="width:300px; height:200px"></div>`

`<script type="text/javascript" src="(link to  downloaded copy of raphaeljs)"></script>`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var paper = Raphael("paper");
var good_cat = paper.image( "http://pp19dd.com/_old/lily.png",40,20,96, 145);
var evil_cat = paper.image( "http://pp19dd.com/_old/cookie.png",160,20,96, 145);
var angle = 0;

setInterval( function() {
    angle += 45;       
    good_cat.stop().animate( { "transform": "R" + angle }, 300, "<>" );
}, 500 );


setInterval( function() {
    r = parseInt(Math.random() * 359);
    evil_cat.stop().animate( { "transform": "R" + r }, 300, "<>" );
}, 1000 );
</script>
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/AJgrU/ for an example.

Comment: +1 for Raphael.js a great js library for image & svg manipulation

Comment: +1 should have been awarded for cats, not for functionality. ;) Thx.

Answer (score 3):

a jsFiddle working example with CSS3 animations and transforms:  <strike>http://jsfiddle.net/GcjKZ/1/</strike>
http://jsfiddle.net/GcjKZ/3/

```
img { position: absolute; width: 25px; height: 25px; 
  -moz-animation: 3s rotate infinite linear  ;
  -moz-transform-origin: 50% 50%; 
  -webkit-animation: 3s rotate infinite linear  ;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;  
}

@-moz-keyframes rotate {
    0    { -moz-transform: rotate(0); } 
    100% { -moz-transform: rotate(360deg); }  
}

@-webkit-keyframes rotate {
    0%    { -webkit-transform: rotate(0); }
    100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); } 
}
```

(sorry, my star is not really well centered)

Comment: Here's one with a centered star :) but the rotation doesnt work? http://jsfiddle.net/GcjKZ/2/

Comment: I didn't mean "centered" on the window. I were talking about the center of the figure with respect to its shape. Your fiddle it's working for me

Comment: My bad, anyways i'm using chrome 18.0.1025.152 m, works perfect in ff though

Comment: Uh - nice - I think you've found a bug in webkit (or it's just firefox to be more permissive?): it accept `0%` but not `0` inside keyframes: see http://jsfiddle.net/GcjKZ/3/

Answer (score 1):

Try this http://code.google.com/p/jquery-rotate/

And you can do this way:

```
 var angle = 1;
  $(document).ready(function() {
        setInterval(function() {
                $("#pic").rotate(angle);
             }, 100);
 });
```