# How to make svg rotate over its center?

Tags: html, css, animation, svg, css-animations

I need to make a spinner out of given SVG. I have a hard time making in rotate over its own center. How can I achieve this?

```
<svg version="1.1" id="Ebene_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 300 300" style="enable-background:new 0 0 300 300;" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
    .st0{fill:#292929;}
    .st1{fill:#D5D5D5;}
</style>
<path class="st0" d="M150,35c63.5,0,115,51.5,115,115s-51.5,115-115,115S35,213.5,35,150c0-27.9,10-53.6,26.5-73.5L34.7,54
    C13.1,80,0,113.5,0,150c0,82.8,67.2,150,150,150s150-67.2,150-150S232.8,0,150,0V35z"/>
<path class="st1" d="M150,0C103.7,0,62.3,21,34.7,54l26.8,22.5C82.6,51.2,114.4,35,150,35V0z"/>
</svg>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u9teovv1/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
@-webkit-keyframes rotate {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to { 
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

svg.rotate
{
    -webkit-animation-name:             rotate; 
    -webkit-animation-duration:         0.5s; 
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count:  infinite;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
}
```

```html
<svg class="rotate" version="1.1" id="Ebene_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 300 300" style="enable-background:new 0 0 300 300;" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
    .st0{fill:#292929;}
    .st1{fill:#D5D5D5;}
</style>
<path class="st0" d="M150,35c63.5,0,115,51.5,115,115s-51.5,115-115,115S35,213.5,35,150c0-27.9,10-53.6,26.5-73.5L34.7,54
    C13.1,80,0,113.5,0,150c0,82.8,67.2,150,150,150s150-67.2,150-150S232.8,0,150,0V35z"/>
<path class="st1" d="M150,0C103.7,0,62.3,21,34.7,54l26.8,22.5C82.6,51.2,114.4,35,150,35V0z"/>
</svg>
```

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10123700/how-to-make-a-picture-rotate-continuously)

Comment: I improved your answer building a working solution combining your CSS and the original HTML. Hope you don't mind, I just think it's better than provide another answer copying yours.