# Make an interval with rotation

Tags: javascript, jquery, rotation, transform

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Continuous CSS rotation animation on hover, animated back to 0deg on hover out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7988962/continuous-css-rotation-animation-on-hover-animated-back-to-0deg-on-hover-out)

I would like a square continuously rotating. I have this code:

```
var gearBig = $('.gear-big');

gearBig.css({
    'transform': 'rotate(42deg)',
    '-moz-transform': 'rotate(42deg)',
    '-o-transform': 'rotate(42deg)',
    '-webkit-transform': 'rotate(42deg)'
});
```

How can I put an interval in this code? That the gearBig is continuously rotating?

Thank you

Comment: you can use setInterval and clearInterval

Comment: It's already been answered in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7988962/continuous-css-rotation-animation-on-hover-animated-back-to-0deg-on-hover-out

Comment: CSS only: http://cssdesk.com/9vr6C

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var deg = 0;

setInterval(rotate_my_big_ass_gear, 100);

function rotate_my_big_ass_gear() {
    $('.gear-big').css({
        'transform': 'rotate(' + (deg++) + 'deg)',
        '-moz-transform': 'rotate(' + (deg++) + 'deg)',
        '-o-transform': 'rotate(' + (deg++) + 'deg)',
        '-webkit-transform': 'rotate(' + (deg++) + 'deg)' //adds 4 on each iteration
    });
}​
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/dQEJV/)

Answer (score 2):

You could use a plugin like [JQuery Rotate](http://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/wiki/Examples)

Comment: It won't let me add this to my post but here is a fiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/73pXD/