# CSS Image Rotation Transformation

Tags: css, transform

I have this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wvZt2/), and I thought that it would make this image constantly rotate, but it doesn't.

The HTML Used:

```
<img class="rotate" src="http://www.arcelormittal.com/distributionsolutions/content/images/reload_captcha.png" />
```

The CSS Used:

```
.rotate{
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.8s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 0.8s;
    -o-transition-duration: 0.8s;
    transition-duration: 0.8s;
    -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform;
    -moz-transition-property: -moz-transform;
    -o-transition-property: -o-transform;
    transition-property: transform;

    -webkit-transform:rotate(360deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(360deg);
    -o-transform:rotate(360deg);
    transform:rotate(360deg);
}
```

Why isn't the image constantly rotating?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to use an animation because it doesn't have a start and an end to transition from:

```
.rotate {
    -webkit-animation: spin .8s infinite linear;
    animation: spin .8s infinite linear;
}
@-webkit-keyframes spin {
    100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
@-moz-keyframes spin {
    100% { -moz-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
@keyframes spin {
    100% {
        -moz-transform:rotate(360deg);
        -o-transform:rotate(360deg);
        transform:rotate(360deg);
    }
}
```

Comment: Basically the same thing, just remove hover
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7988962/continuous-css-rotation-animation-on-hover-animated-back-to-0deg-on-hover-out

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style> 
        div
        {
            width:200px;
            height:100px;
            margin-top:100px;
            background-color:yellow;
            /* Rotate div */
            transform:rotate(90deg);
            -ms-transform:rotate(90deg); /* IE 9 */
            -webkit-transform:rotate(90deg); /* Opera, Chrome, and Safari */
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div><img src="http://www.rltech.co.in/01/images/rllogo.png"/></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please add some content to your answer. Code only answers are not appreciated.