# Image transform rotate not rotating

Tags: html, css, transform, css-transforms

I am trying to get an image of an X I have to rotate 180 degrees when it is being hovered over, however it is just moving up and to the right instead of rotating.

What am I doing wrong that this won't look like it is spinning 180 degrees?

```css
.black {
  background: #000;
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
}
.popup-close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  right: 40px;
}
#x-close:hover {
  -webkit-transform: translate(50%, -50%) rotate(180deg);
  transform: translate(50%, -50%) rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="black">
  <a class="popup-close" data-popup-close="popup-1" href="#">
    <img src="http://optimumwebdesigns.com/icons/delete-cross.png" alt="" height="40px" width="40px" id="x-close">
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried adding a transition value? try adding `#x-close{transition: all 400ms ease;}` to your CSS

Comment: You're also using translate to move the centre so the rotation will be pinned in the middle.. so after the rotation you need to reverse the translation to put it back in the same location (but rotated).  I don't know if you can queue css translate/rotate like that though...

Comment: The transition timing helped. So, @PeteB are you saying to do something like `#x-close:hover after{}` then something?

Comment: Actually this is a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17619217/css-image-rotation-transformation?rq=1 so you should look there first

Comment: @PeteB: Depends on what Becky is trying to do. I don't think the aim here is for continuous rotation (assuming based on what is described in question) and moreover the question doesn't ask *how to achieve*, it asks *why* what they've tried isn't working. So, I don't think this is 100% dupe of that one. But then, opinions could vary :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The cross moves up (and to the right) because of the `translate` transform that you are adding when it is being hovered. I believe you are adding this to center the element and in that case, it is better that it is added to the default state of the element itself.

The rotate ***is actually happening*** but you aren't seing it because a 180deg rotate of a cross gives the same output. You can add a transition to see the rotation (or) change the rotation angle.

```css
.black {
  background: #000;
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
}
.popup-close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  right: 40px;
}
#x-close {
  transform: translate(50%, -50%);
  transition: transform 1s ease;
}
#x-close:hover {
  -webkit-transform: translate(50%, -50%) rotate(180deg);
  transform: translate(50%, -50%) rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="black">
  <a class="popup-close" data-popup-close="popup-1" href="#">
    <img src="http://optimumwebdesigns.com/icons/delete-cross.png" alt="" height="40px" width="40px" id="x-close">
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Working **[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/UI_Designer/p2mkmksg/)**

add this is css in your code:

```
 #x-close{
       -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .8s ease-in-out;
      transition: transform .8s ease-in-out;
        -webkit-transform: translate(50%, -50%);
        transform: translate(50%, -50%) ; 
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution

```
@-webkit-keyframes spin {
    100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg); }
}
@-moz-keyframes spin {
    100% { -moz-transform: rotate(180deg); }
}
@keyframes spin {
    100% {
        -moz-transform:rotate(180deg);
        -o-transform:rotate(180deg);
        transform:rotate(180deg);
    }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hk2ums6p/

Answer (score 0):

This should do it :

```
#x-close:hover {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
    transform: rotate(180deg);
    -webkit-transition: transform 0.5s ease;    
    transition: transform 0.5s ease;
}
```

Comment: Won't this rotate around the bottom-left corner though?