# CSS rotate property won't apply to all gallery images

Tags: html, css

HTML

```
<div class="photos"> 
<img src="images/p1.jpg" />
<img src="images/p2.jpg" />
.............
</div>
```

CSS

```
.photos img:hover {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg) scale(1.5);
    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg) scale(1.5);
    -o-transform: rotate(360deg) scale(1.5);
    transform: rotate(360deg) scale(1.5);
    z-index: 10;}
```

why is the above CSS rotate property applied only to **p1.jpg** ?

Comment: You realise this will only work for images you are hovering over?

Comment: yes i do,it works when i hover p1,when i hover any of the rest they'd only scale but not rotate..

Answer (score 1):

Because you're only hovering on `p1.jpg` the CSS selector will only be fired on the image you are hovering.

If you just wan't each image to rotate seperatly, add these lines to your css.

```
-webkit-transition: all 1.2s linear;
-moz-transition: all 1.2s linear;
-o-transition: all 1.2s linear;
-ms-transition: all 1.2s linear;
transition: all 1.2s linear;
```

Unfortunately, what you're asking for will require some JavaScript to make happen.

Comment: ok i meant that when i hover p2 for example,it won't rotate,same for the rest,only p1 rotates when hovered.

Comment: Try removing the trailing slash from your `img` tags. You don't need to close them with `/>`, simply `>` will do. It's a long shot, but that might be it.

Answer (score 1):

Rotate works. Angle of 360 degrees brings the image in the same position. Use transform with transition or change the angle value.

So, your code will be something like:

```
.photos img {
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1.2s linear;
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform 1.2s linear;
    -o-transition: -o-transform 1.2s linear;
    -ms-transition: -ms-transform 1.2s linear;
    transition: transform 1.2s linear;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.photos img:hover { 
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg) scale(1.5);
    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg) scale(1.5);
    -o-transform: rotate(360deg) scale(1.5);
    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg) scale(1.5);
    transform: rotate(360deg) scale(1.5);
    z-index: 10;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7988962/continuous-css-rotation-animation-on-hover-animated-back-to-0deg-on-hover-out) can help you..

```
    .elem{
    -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 1s;

    -moz-transition-property: -moz-transform;
    -moz-transition-duration: 1s;
}
.elem:hover {
    -webkit-animation-name: rotate; 
    -webkit-animation-duration: 2s; 
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;

    -moz-animation-name: rotate; 
    -moz-animation-duration: 2s; 
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: linear;
}
@-webkit-keyframes rotate {
    from {-webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);}
    to {-webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);}
}

@-moz-keyframes rotate {
    from {-moz-transform: rotate(0deg);}
    to {-moz-transform: rotate(360deg);}
}
```

Comment: i think i figured out where's the problem,all the rest of the images except for p1 are already rotated by some degree.

Answer (score 0):

There was no issue with your code. The rotate was working on all the elements of the div. The only reason you could not see it was because you did not have a *`delay or duration`* for the '***transformation***'.

I have used the same code that 'Dragos Sandu' has used. Only change I suggest is the "***ease-in-out***" for the duration. specially when the change is only 1.2 seconds. This make the change "***easy on the eye***".

CSS

```
.photos img:hover {
    transform: rotate(360deg) scale(1.5);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg) scale(1.5);
    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg) scale(1.5);
    -o-transform: rotate(360deg) scale(1.5);
    z-index: 10;
    -webkit-transition: all 1.2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 1.2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 1.2s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 1.2s ease-in-out;
}
```

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9jTCc/3/)