# Animated FontAwesome in Css

Tags: fonts, font-awesome

I am writing a website that is not using bootstrap. Thus in order to use font-awesome I am using the following css rules

CSS

```
[data-icon]:before {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  font-size: 90%;
  color: white;   
  margin-right: .5em;
  content: attr(data-icon);
  speak: none;
  z-index: 11;
}
.icon-alone {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

And I am using it in the HTML as such:

```
<head>
  <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  <span data-icon="&#xf110;"></span>
</body>
```

Now I would like to make the the icon to spin (as shown in the examples in the font-awesome examples page.

Is this is possible using css rules...

Many Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, they use the following:

```
@-moz-keyframes spin {
0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
}
100% {
    transform: rotate(359deg);
}
}
.fa-spin {
    animation: 2s linear 0s normal none infinite spin;
}
```

(Probably with the other vendor prefixes as well, but they seem to sniff the browser and send only the appropriate one.)

Comment: Thanks, but it seems to rotate around an off-centre point (that is to the right of the centre)... Is there any way to solve this...

Comment: You'll have to check the [relevant CSS code](http://fontawesome.io/assets/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css).

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is something you're looking for:

[Continuous CSS rotation animation on hover, animated back to 0deg on hover out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7988962/continuous-css-rotation-animation-on-hover-animated-back-to-0deg-on-hover-out)

I guess you want the 'loading' icon to spin infinitely. If you wish to acquire this effect using javascript you can just use jQuery and the .css method with a setInterval. I believe this is the better approach since I heard they were having some issues with the jsFiddle on other browsers than the 'webkit' ones.