# How to keep playing a CSS animation after refreshing (hide/show) the DOM using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have some code that updates a price and I want to animate the price badges so it attracts more attention. This animation is fired when changing a `select` element.

For some reason the animation only plays the first change but not after that. I figured it was because the DOM refreshed so the animation was no longer applied on the new element. That is why instead of directly calling the class in my code I traversed to it from `$(this)` but this also doesn't work.

What am I doing wrong?

My html:

```
<div class="col-md-9 col-lg-6 col-xl-5 pl-lg-5 pl-xl-0 order-lg-2 boxclosest" data-aos="fade-left" data-aos-delay="250">
    <h1 class="display-3">Roti Box</h1>
    <p>Berspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam.</p>
    <div class="boxkeuze">
        <span>Maak je keuze:</span>
        <select id="boxkeuze" name="boxkeuze">
            <option box="roti-box" value="prijs-box-per-aantal-personen0" selected>Box voor 1 persoon</option>
            <option box="roti-box" value="prijs-box-per-aantal-personen1">Box voor 2 personen</option>
            <option box="roti-box" value="prijs-box-per-aantal-personen2">Box voor 4 personen</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <a href="recepten/roti-recept" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg mx-sm-2 mx-lg-0 mr-lg-2 my-1 my-sm-0 groenbtn">Bekijk recept</a> <a href="winkelwagen" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg mx-sm-2 mx-lg-0 mr-lg-2 my-1 my-sm-0">Bestellen</a>
</div>
<div class="col-md-8 col-lg-6 mt-4 mt-md-5 mt-lg-0 order-lg-1 boxsibling" data-aos="fade-right">
    <img src="cms/images/boxen/roti-box/Roti-1-1-1200x18001.jpg" alt="Image" class="rounded img-fluid shadow-lg" />
    <span id="oldprice" class="pricebadgeold boxdetailpadding">€ 59,99</span>
    <span id="price" class="pricebadge boxdetailpadding">€ 49,99</span>
</div>
```

Here my jQuery code with commented both ways I tried it:

```
$('body').on('change', '#boxkeuze', function(event) {
  boxinfo = $(this).children("option:selected").val();
  alias = $(this).children("option:selected").attr('box');
  $.ajax({
   type:'post',
   url:"ajax/updateprice.php",
   data:({boxinfo: boxinfo, alias: alias}),
   success:function(data){
     var obj = JSON.parse(data);
     // I tried it this way
     $(this).closest('.boxclosest').siblings('.boxsibling').children('.pricebadge').hide().text('€ ' + obj[0].price).addClass('updatepriceanim').show();
     // And this way
     $( "#oldprice" ).hide().text('€ ' + obj[0].priceold).addClass('updatepriceanim').show();
   }
  });
});
```

Like I said the animation works fine the first time (only if I try it like this though: `$( "#oldprice" ).hide().text('€ ' + obj[0].priceold).addClass('updatepriceanim').show();` the other way doesn't work at all) but after that it stops working.

My animation:

```
@keyframes scale-drop-down {
  0%   {transform:scale(.8)}
  100% {transform:scale(1)}
}

.updatepriceanim{
  animation: scale-drop-down .25s cubic-bezier(.1,1.45,.35,1);
  transform-origin: top right;
}
```

Comment: Your css animation code here will also help in understanding

Comment: Also you can see `animation-iteration-count` for example here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7988962/continuous-css-rotation-animation-on-hover-animated-back-to-0deg-on-hover-out

Comment: @kewlashu I added the CSS but that is not really my issue. The animation works fine, but only the first time. I think this is a jQuery issue and not a CSS issue.

Comment: your animation not working at all :(

Comment: @gpl It works for me, I don't know what you mean?