# How to continuously rotate an icon on hover?

Tags: javascript, html

Icon rotates for 3-4 seconds but not continuously on hovering.Now it is revolving around After adding the changes. Please help.

Comment: Please may you replace the image with a [mcve]? We can't debug an image

Comment: Please take the [tour] and see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. We'll need to see your markup, too.

Comment: i dont think it can work on a link tag

Comment: Also duplicate of [Continuous CSS rotation animation on hover, animated back to 0deg on hover out](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7988962/215552)

Comment: there is a typo in your code, its a <i> tag but you have written it to be <a>

Comment: POST YOUR CODE.... We can not copy and paste from an image

Comment: and you are writing those tags in wrong place style should be between head tag and other html tags should be in body tag

Comment: @VardanaBhanot No, it's an `a` tag. There is no requirement that anything has to be an `i` tag. That is a convention, but not a requirement.

Comment: @HereticMonkey thank you for correcting me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this I hope this works for you

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <style>
    i:hover {
      animation: rotation 3s infinite linear;
    }
    
    @keyframes rotation {
      from {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
      }
      to {
        transform: rotate(359deg);
      }
    }
    </style>
    <title>My Project</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
    <i class="fa fa-times"/>
    </div>
 </body>

</html>
```

Comment: not working. Still working for 3 to 4 seconds

Comment: May you add some HTML and convert it to a snippet so we can see it running?

Comment: sure i will do that

Comment: This is also the same technique used on the answers to the duplicate question...

Comment: Now i have given the snippet also. Please help

Comment: thank you Vardana Bhanot. Its working noww

Comment: Just mark the answer correct if possible sir @VarunArora

Comment: okk done.......